# binary16 in Python

Tags: python, struct, floating-point, format, packing

The [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module is useful when you're trying to convert data to and from binary formats. However, recently I came across a file format specification that uses [the binary16 floating point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_precision_floating-point_format). I looked through the Python documentation, but can't find anything that can convert to and from it. What would be the best way to convert this data to/from Python floats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it roughly like you'd do it in C -- i.e., I think, roughly like this...:

```
def tofloat(b16):
  sign = -1 if b16 & 0x8000 else +1
  expo = ( b16 & 0x7C00 ) >> 10
  prec = b16 & 0x03FF
  if expo == 0:
    return sign * (2.0 ** -24) * prec
  elif expo == 0x1F:
    return sign * float('inf')
  prec |= 0x0400
  return sign * (2.0 ** (expo - 25)) * prec
```

Answer (score 2):

[This guy's blog post](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2008/12/half-precision-floating-point-format_14.html) gives an implementation in both and python.  He uses the `struct` module, then decodes it manually.  It is not all that complicated a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search turned up http://packages.python.org/bigfloat/ which says it has a context for manipulation of `binary16` floating-point numbers. I'm not familiar with the package myself, though, so I couldn't tell you anything about how to use it (at least, nothing more than you can read yourself in the documentation).